# Continuously restart container in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, grafana

I am working on ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l) and I have some troubles with Docker.
I did soft link the Docker Root Directory to `/media/sd` (SD card). Now I am installing Grafana (software) on it. I have trouble with continuously restarting container on it.

This is what I did:

`docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name=grafana --restart=on-failure grafana/grafana`

What I got?
Logs from docker: (docker logs grafana):

> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Is there a way to fix things up?
I would be grateful.

Comment: `custom Linux` what architecture are you running on?

Comment: Linux PFC200V3-43C500 4.9.146-rt125w02.09.01 #1 PREEMPT RT Wed Jul 15 17:05:09 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l

Comment: `ARMv7` most probably you are trying to run x86_64 docker on a ARMv7 platform... The `exec format error` is most probably coming from the linker when detecting the format of the executable. Check your docker configuration and configured platform.

Comment: OK, that is possible. I did docker pull grafana from linux on x86_64 and then load the image using ftp to open it on destinaton device. 
Is there a way to download image of ARM architecture on win10 (laptop at hand)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using the wrong architecture in your setup. I assume you're either building the image on an amd64 machine and pushing this image on a remote system or pulling the image from an amd64 and transferring the image on a arm64 in a second stage.

In the first case, I suggest to build the image directly on the arm64 machine. In the second case, I suggest to pull the grafana image for that specific architecture. Check the grafana page https://hub.docker.com/r/grafana/grafana/tags to get the image digest. e.g. if you need to pull the image 7.2.0 for arm, you'll need to use the pull command using the image and the sha digest (in this case sha256:8c8be98e7999106471369b914a8cb9205ac2b3c43cca2f4e5cc5c792e3fbfacd). In other words:

```sh
docker pull grafana/grafana@sha256:8c8be98e7999106471369b914a8cb9205ac2b3c43cca2f4e5cc5c792e3fbfacd

docker save -o grafana.tar grafana/grafana@sha256:8c8be98e7999106471369b914a8cb9205ac2b3c43cca2f4e5cc5c792e3fbfacd
```

transfer the files to the remote machine

```sh
docker load -i grafana.tar
```

Comment: lol... I just noticed now that I answered the question about the saving and loading images :)

Comment: If you are still here, can you tell me how to give a name to image?
I did docker images, and there is a number which is not eye-friendly.
It is a way to change it to e.g. grafana?

Comment: `docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]`

Comment: God bless you :)